# Is there a Wiki with a Web 2.0 UI (like StackOverflow's)?

Tags: ajax, wiki, wysiwyg, confluence, mindtouch

I need to use MediaWiki at work. It used to be okay, but with sites s.a. StackOverflow, there's some user interface issues that simply don't do any more.

Most importantly, I'd want to see the live preview when typing. There shouldn't be need for a preview mode.

What Wikis are you using? Which would be the best for a recent (easy) Web experience?

Can MediaWiki be updated to have more recent UI behaviour?

***Addendum:***

Two products seem to be above others, both "open source commercial" (= you get a skinny version free, standard and enterprise levels with more goodies cost).

- [MindTouch DekiWiki](http://www.mindtouch.com/products)
- [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/)

Judge for yourself. I sure found my liking in one of these. :)

Comment: MediaWiki 1.5 alpha 1 seems to have something for this itch:

* 'live preview' reduces preview reload burden on supported browsers

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Live_preview

Comment: WikiWig has been mentioned here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871/getting-developers-to-use-a-wiki

Comment: http://www.mindtouch.com/Products/Demo_Gallery looks reeeeeally good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a WYSIWYG extension for mediawiki. See [Fckeditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_(by_Mafs)):

[image: Fckeditor5]

Answer (score 2):

Well there is [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) (which is the StackOverflow engine), but you have to pay for it.

Comment: Thanks! Only heard about that now. Will be glad to try out the beta.

Answer (score 2):

A discussion  on Confluence vs Mediawiki: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/Confluence+Vs+Mediawiki

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have the preview feature you talk about, but you asked for "favorite wikis", so here's mine (at least favorite for ease of use/setup):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ScrewTurn_Wiki

http://www.screwturn.eu/